# Why is an inductive load presented as a resistor on schematic diagrams?

Tags: resistors

The presentation of a resistor load, such as a light bulb, as a resistor on a schematic diagram makes sense to me. However, why do we present inductive loads as such, seeing it isn't a resistor as such?

Comment: Please show an example as inductors are NOT represented as resistors in normal schematics. You might confuse it with the symbol of an impedance.

Comment: @Oldfart Thank you for pointing this out. Phil Frost also makes that point below. I do believe the resistor symbol is used to represent a "load of some type" as Kyle B points out below, and so I might have assumed, by convention, we present a known inductive load using a resistor symbol, which appears not to be true. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resistor symbol is commonly used to indicate "There is a load here of some type", even if that load is not a resistor.   It's just a convenient way to simplify schematic concepts.  It does not mean inductors=resistors.

Technically, light bulbs are not resistors either.  Their resistance is highly non-linear, and they do not behave like resistors.

Comment: Actually, they are resistors. They are not linear resistors, but the fact that voltage depends on current - albeit in a nonlinear manner - and the time derivatives of V and I are not required makes them resistors. (They have negligible parasitic inductance and capacitance, and I seriously doubt they can be considered memristors).

Comment: When you first apply current to a light bulb, its basically a short-circuit.    As you slowly bring up the voltage on a filament bulb from zero, nothing happens at first.  At some point, the filament suddenly "ignites", starts to glow, and it's resistance rises dramatically.  This also drives the current down.  Then you can continue to raise source voltage, the current goes up again.   So for a filament bulb there are TWO different currents that can result from the same voltage.  That is not an ohmic load, and ergo it is not a resistor.  #hysteresis   IMHO of course   ;)

Comment: @KyleB Thanks for clearing this up for me!

Comment: Chua, Desoer, Kuh, "Linear and Nonlinear Circuits", p.52. You will discover that even a glow tube is a nonlinear resistor. And yes, it will show that you can have two different values of current for the same value of voltage. There are only four types of elements: resistors, inductors, capacitors and memristors. A lamp is not an inductor, is not a capacitor and is not a memristor. It is a resistor- A nonlinear one, but still a resistor.

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite certain there is no established convention to draw inductive loads as resistors. That doesn't mean you won't find examples of laziness or errors.

I have seen schematics drawn like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0qadJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

While some styles of schematic draw all resistors as rectangles, another style is to draw resistors as zig-zag lines like R1 above. The rectangle style is then used for things which are either some unknown load (perhaps an external device) or some potentially complex impedance which might represent some more complicated assembly when the particulars of that assembly aren't especially relevant to the point at hand.